# How to refer to a value by key in unity Newtonsoftjson

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

I am getting json string from database.
It looks something like this:

```
{
  "0": "Test0",
  "1": "Testdwa",
  "2": "Testik",
  "3": "Tests"
}
```

The length can be indefinite (That is, there may not be 4, but more lines).
But I can't figure out how to get values by key (That is, I want to get the string "Testik" by key "2").
I also use "Newtonsoft.Json" in my script.

But I am a beginner, so it is desirable that you explain something in simple terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to parse a json at first

```
var jsonParsed=JObject.Parse(json);
```

after this you can use the object the same way  as a dictionary

```
string testic = (string) jsonParsed["2"]; // "Testic"
//or
var testdwa = (string) jsonParsed["1"]; // "Testdwa"
```

another way is to deserialiaze json to c# object (Dictionary<string,string> in this case

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict= JsonConverter.ToObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(json);
```

you can get data the same way, only you don't need to cast them

```
string testic = dict["2"]; // "Testic"
```